# Can we import a class present in /src/main/scala to /src/main/java

Tags: java, scala, class, import, package

I am new to scala guys and  I have a scala code in my project, now I wish to add some java parser classes to this proejct and I am trying to keep the Java and scala code separate in my project repository.
I have some parser java classes copied from another repository which I want to keep separate in /src/main/java and the code which is using these parser classes sits in /src/main/scala, so now when I try to import that package which is present under /src/main/java it is not able to locate that class and I am getting compilation error in import. is there a way to import a package present under different java directory into scala class present in scala directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to compile the project? AFAIK **sbt** handles this automatically and I would guess any other build tool should do the same

Comment: I am using maven and IDE is intelliJ

Comment: Have you confirmed the problem happens if you use **maven** to compile the code?

Comment: yes I am using maven only

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the -cp directive with javac so that you can compile from multiple directories.

But the better way to do this would be to compile your scala code separately first and put it in a JAR file. Then you can just include the jar for compilation and runtime

[https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Escottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm)